# ACM Image Compression Algorithm C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression

I've been trying to get better at c++, so I've been solving problems designed for programming contests. I started this problem a few days ago, and cannot solve it for the life of me. I need some help with my algorithm and how to fix it. This is the problem: [ACM Image Compression problem](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=404&page=show_problem&problem=2927)

**MY CODE:** I explain it underneath.

```
#include "Compress.h"
using namespace std;

Compress::Compress(){
    size = 0, threshold = 0, nRows=0, nCols=0;
    // Enter in a file name
    cout << "Welcome. Please type in the name of the file to read the numbers.\n";
    cin >> readFileName;

    inFile.open(readFileName.c_str());
    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open the file! Press Enter to exit..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //Finding the array size and threshold
    inFile >> size >> threshold;

    nRows = size;
    nCols = size;
    topright = size;
    bottomleft = size;

    //Let's make the array
    // creating the columns
    compressArray = new int* [nCols];

    // creating the rows
    for (int r = 0; r < nRows; r++){
        compressArray[r] = new int[nRows];
    }

    // FIll the array
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
            inFile >> compressArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    // Show before editing.
    print();
    work(0, nRows, 0, nCols);

}
Compress::~Compress(){
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i ++){
        delete compressArray[i];
    }
    delete [] compressArray;
}


void Compress::work(int start_x, int end_x, int start_y, int end_y){
    int nb_blacks = 0;
    int nb_whites = 0;
    int total_blocks = 0;
    int majority = 0;
    int percent = 0;

     cout << start_x << end_x << start_y << end_y << "\n------\n";

    for(int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++){
        for(int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++){
            if(compressArray[i][j] == 1){
                nb_blacks++;
            }
        }
    }

    total_blocks = ((end_x - start_x) * (end_y - start_y));
    nb_whites = total_blocks - nb_blacks;

    // give the max back
    majority = max(nb_blacks, nb_whites);
    // find the percent of the highest amount of colored blocks.
    percent = ((majority*100)/total_blocks);

    cout << "\n----\nPercent: " << percent << " Threshold: " << threshold  << endl;



    // majority/total_blocks is determining the percent of the greater
    // color in the box. We are comparing it to the threshold percent.
    if (percent >= threshold){
        for(int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++){
            for(int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++){
                if(nb_blacks > nb_whites) compressArray[i][j] = 1;
                else compressArray[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
            topright = topright/2;
            bottomleft = bottomleft/2;

            work(start_x, (end_x/2), (topright), end_y);
            work(start_x, (end_x/2), start_y, (end_y/2));
            work((bottomleft), end_x, start_y, (end_y/2));
            work((bottomleft), end_x, (topright), end_y);

    }

}

void Compress::print(){
    for (int r = 0; r < nRows; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < nCols; c++){
            cout << compressArray[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

So, what my program does is count the number of black squares in the image (1's). It than compares it to the number of white squares (0's). Whichever is larger, is turned into a percent based on how many squares are in the image. It compares it with the threshold. If the threshold is smaller than the percent... The whole image turned the majority color.

If the threshold is higher... It breaks into four recursive parts and zooms in. It will start with the top right, then top left, bottom left, and bottom right.

My program works with a 4 by 4 square, because it breaks into four parts correctly. However, with the 8 by 8 square... if it needs to be broken into smaller than four parts, everything messes up.

I know why it does this. My algorithm for zooming in the recursive function is wrong. If the square is an 8 by 8... the parameters would be something like

> 0, 8, 0, 8 = looking at the whole square
>
> 0, 4, 4, 8 = the top right
>
> corner using a 4 by 4 0, 2, 6, 8 = looking at the smallest top right
>
> square of a 2 by 2.

I just don't know a mathematical function that would get what I need. I have no idea how to fix this for 8 by 8 squares. Is my code even possible to fix? Or do I need to figure out another way of going about it? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it! The mathematical function was just being a pain.

**Header Function**

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>


using namespace std;

class Compress{
    public:
        Compress();
        ~Compress();
        void input();
        void work(int start_x, int end_x, int start_y, int end_y);
        void print();

    private:
        int size;
        int threshold;
        int** compressArray;
        int nRows, nCols;

        string readFileName;
        ifstream inFile;
};
```

**CPP FILE**

```
#include "Compress.h"
using namespace std;

Compress::Compress(){
    size = 0, threshold = 0, nRows=0, nCols=0;
    // Enter in a file name
    cout << "Welcome. Please type in the name of the file to read the numbers.\n";
    cin >> readFileName;

    // Open the file.
    inFile.open(readFileName.c_str());
    if(!inFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open the file! Press Enter to exit..." << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    //Finding the array size and threshold
    inFile >> size;

    nRows = size;
    nCols = size;

    // Enter a threshold.
    cout << "Enter the desired threshold between 50-100: ";
    cin >> threshold;

    // Keep asking for the desired threshold until it is given.
    while (threshold < 50 || threshold > 100){
        cout << "\nIncorrect Threshold.\n";
        cout << "Enter the desired threshold between 50-100: ";
        cin >> threshold;
    }


    //Let's make the array
    // creating the columns
    compressArray = new int* [nCols];

    // creating the rows
    for (int r = 0; r < nRows; r++){
        compressArray[r] = new int[nCols];
    }

    // FIll the array
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++){
            inFile >> compressArray[i][j];
        }
    }

    inFile.close();

    // Show before editing.
    print();
    work(0, nRows, 0, nCols);

}
Compress::~Compress(){
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i ++){
        delete compressArray[i];
    }
    delete [] compressArray;
}


void Compress::work(int start_x, int end_x, int start_y, int end_y){
    int Size = end_y - start_y; // Finding the midpoints.
    int nb_blacks = 0;
    int nb_whites = 0;
    int total_blocks = 0;
    int majority = 0;
    int percent = 0;

//    Testing everything.

//    cout << "\nx1, y1: " << start_x << "," << start_y << " x2,y2: " << end_x << "," << end_y << endl;
//    for (int r = start_x; r < end_x; r++){
//        for (int c = start_y; c < end_y; c++){
//            cout << compressArray[r][c];
//        }
//        cout << endl;
//    }

    // Initial case. If 1, break and start returning results
    if (end_x <= start_x || end_y <= start_y){
        return;
    }

   //  Keep breaking it down until it reaches 1.
    else {
        // Count the Number of Black pieces
        for(int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++){
            for(int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++){
                if(compressArray[i][j] == 1){
                    nb_blacks++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Find the total and number of white pieces.
        total_blocks = ((end_x - start_x) * (end_y - start_y));
        nb_whites = total_blocks - nb_blacks;

        // give the max back
        majority = max(nb_blacks, nb_whites);
        // find the percent of the highest amount of colored blocks.
        percent = ((majority*100)/total_blocks);

//        cout << "Percent: " << percent << " Threshold: " << threshold  << "\n-----\n";


        // majority/total_blocks is determining the percent of the greater
        // color in the box. We are comparing it to the threshold percent.
        if (percent >= threshold){
            for(int i = start_x; i < end_x; i++){
                for(int j = start_y; j < end_y; j++){
                    if(nb_blacks > nb_whites) compressArray[i][j] = 1;
                    else compressArray[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        // Keep breaking down until we reach the initial case.
        else {
            work((end_x - (Size/2)), (end_x), (start_y), (start_y + (Size/2)));
            work(start_x, (start_x + (Size/2)), (start_y), (start_y + (Size/2)));
            work((start_x), (start_x + (Size/2)), (end_y - (Size/2)), end_y);
            work((end_x - (Size/2)), end_x, (end_y - (Size/2)), end_y);
//
//            work((start_x), (mid_x), (mid_y), end_y);
//            work(start_x, (mid_x ), (start_y), (mid_y));
//            work((mid_x), end_x, start_y, (mid_y));
//            work((mid_x), end_x, (mid_y), end_y);
        }
    }
}

void Compress::print(){

    // Print the function
    cout << "\nImage: " << threshold << "%\n";
    for (int r = 0; r < nRows; r++){
        for (int c = 0; c < nCols; c++){
            cout << compressArray[r][c];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your reading routine has some problems:

The second array creation loop is wrong, should use `nCols` as the limit of the loop instead of `nRows`:

```
// creating the rows
for (int r = 0; r < nCols; r++){
    // Remember you're creating the "row"s for every column
    compressArray[r] = new int[nRows];
}
```

Based on the problem enunciate, the input format does not contain spaces between the bitmap pixels, so you have to read a line of data and then iterate over the line to extract individual chars:

```
// FIll the array
for (int i = 0; i < nRows; i++){
    // You should #include <string> for this to work
    string line;
    inFile >> line;
    for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++) 
        compressArray[i][j] = line[j] - '0';
}
```

After the reading is done, you can add some improvements to the `work` routine:

The formula you're looking for is not rocket science, take a look of the following image:

[image]

Just partitionate the bitmap like that and make the respective invocations to `work` for every sector (don't see the use for the `top/bottom`-`right/left` variables here thought)

Your algorithm is a recursive one, but there is not initial case, so your algorithm executes  indefinitely, you should check if the difference between `start` and `end` is 0 before any recursive invocation.

There are another caveats, but you should first fix these up before continuing

IMO, your idea for solving this problem is good, just need a little polishing

Hope this helps!

**PS:** *Is a really good (if not one of the best) practice to apply OOP fundamentals (such as classes) for general software development, but for Programming Contests consider the time factor and the software complexity of the developed solution, is not bad, but take into account that in many cases it could lead you to waste time and to add some unnecessary  complexity*

Comment: You are right about nCols when creating the Dynamic Array. I was just being careless as the rows and columns will always have the same size.

About filling the array, I didn't mention it but I did put spaces between each number so it would fill the array correctly. 

However, I am not exactly sure what you are saying for the formula. I know I need to find the midpoint of the graph and somehow use that to make my recursion, but at the moment I'm not seeing how it does it (probably from staring at this problem too long)

And whoops, I did forget the initial case.